# Attaching Image to Custom Object in Salesforce1

Tags: apex, visualforce, salesforce1-app, custom-object

After doing a bit of research, I have come up with the following code (I apologize if part of the code doesn't make sense).
I have created the following visualforce page

```
    <apex:page standardController="PVID__c" extensions="StandardController"> 
        <script src="/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='/canvas/sdk/js/publisher.js'/>
        <script src="https://mobile1.t.salesforce.com/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript" />
        <script>
        function myUpdate()
        {
        var accountId = document.getElementById('accountId').value;

        Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
        '{!$RemoteAction.StandardController.standardController}', accountId, function(result, event)
        {
         if(result!=null) sforce.one.navigateToSObject(result,"detail");
        Sfdc.canvas.publisher.publish({name: "publisher.close", payload:{ refresh:"true"}});

        });
        }
        </script>

        <apex:form >

            <h1>Visit</h1>
            <table cellspacing="20"> 
                <tr>
                    <td>Local Spaces</td>
                </tr> 
                <tr>            
                    <td style="padding:0 15px 0 15px;" ><apex:inputField value="{!PVID__c.Common_Areas_Text__c}" style="width: 300px; height: 50px"/></td>
                    <td style="padding:0 15px 0 15px;" ><apex:inputField value="{!PVID__c.Common_Areas_Rating__c}" style="width: 120px; height: 20px"/></td>
                </tr>     
            </table>

            <input id="photoFile" type="file" accept="image/*"/>

            <a href="#" data-role="button" onclick="myUpdate()">Save</a>

        </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

My StandardController apex class

```
public with sharing class StandardController {
    public ApexPages.StandardController standardController { get; set; }
    public StandardController(ApexPages.StandardController standardController) {
        this.standardController = standardController;
    }
}
```

What I am finding hard to accomplish.

1. Attaching a pic to my custom-object (PVID__c)
2. By default, when you press back button on android Salesforce1 app, it closes. I want to navigate back to previous visualforce page.

Errors:

[image]